# gcse probability

Tags: probability

a bag contains ten counters four of the counters are red in an experiment three counters are taken from the bag at random and put in a box

calculate the probability that there are exactly two red counters In the box

this is what I have done 4/10*3/10= 3/25 2 - 3/25 = 47/25 is this correct? please explain if not correct

Comment: The probability can't be greater than $1$!

Comment: Hint:  what is the probability that you will draw the exact sequence $RRX$ (where $X$ just means "not red")?  What about $RXR$?  $XRR$?

Comment: @ lulu, so is the probability of not getting a red is 1- 3/10 = 7/10 if I draw a tree diagram will it help?

Comment: Perhaps, but I think it is more direct to do it the way I sketched.

Comment: Make sure you remember:  the probabilities shift after each draw.  the probability of getting $R$ first is $\frac 4{10}$.  Given that you got an $R$ first, the probability of getting a second $R$ on the second draw is now $\frac 3{9}$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Two red counters = $\binom 42$

Non-red counters = $\binom 61$

Probability = $\frac{\binom 42 × \binom 61}{\binom {10}3}$